# set permissions on an entity as though it were a node

Tags: 7, users, entities

I am using the [Field Collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module to create entities for other nodes.  I would like to administer the creation/editing/viewing permissions for these entities using the permissions page in the same way as other node content types.  Is this possible (maybe with another module?)

Comment: "create entities for other nodes"  can you explain me what does this mean ?

Comment: Have you tried any of the field access modules or techniques?

Comment: @shrish Field Collection defines a new entity type (field_collection_item), which you can then field out.  It also defined a new field type which can reference field_collection_items, and add these to nodes.